# Multiverse theory VS Conformal Cyclic Cosmology (CCC)

Tags: cosmology, conformal-field-theory, big-bang, cosmological-inflation, multiverse

[Multiverse theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse) describes that there are many singularities taking birth and then based on their properties (like dark matter content), these may pop in and out of existence. While on the other hand, Roger Penrose's [Conformal Cyclic Cosmology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_cyclic_cosmology) (CCC) claims the condition at the end of the universe is similar to that as of it's start and this may give birth to another big bang. And this cycles on. So does the two theory oppose each other? Because in CCC, there is only $one$ big bang which keeps on repeating while multiverse theory says that there are $many$ big bangs taking place. Is it possible both the theories can be united to give a better theory combined having both the features? (I know this is beyond experimental proof but just for the sake of it, let's assume that both theories have a chance of being correct)

$\mathbf {EDIT:}$ On the other hand, only talking about CCC, is it possible that the conditions of the last stage of universe may give rise to many separate big bangs instead of only one, thus being consistent with multiverse theory?

Comment: I haven't read "Cycles of Time" (Penrose's 2010 pop-sci book detailing his cosmology) recently enough to post an answer within the present condition of my PSE reputation, but his 2020 receipt of a Nobel prize for his singularity theorems formulated a half-century earlier, and his status as a mathematical physicist, definitely gives his views a certain amount of credibility.  It should be noted that CCC is past- and future-eternal, and a disproportionate share of physicists' salaries are paid in a very populous country (the U.S.) where past eternality encounters widespread religious objections.

Answer (score -1):

In multiverse theory the collisions of Branes leads to big bang.  Once a Big Bang happens gravity is also borne.  Gravity is borne to take care of balance of the creation.  Also it is told that gravity communicates with other universes.  The communication of gravity with others is to tell there is a creation within and to stop collisions taking place again and again by acting like a shock absorbers.  At the end of the creation i.e., at the time of big crunch everything vanishes and gravity also. So once again the Universe is ready for collision with other Universes to give rise to a fresh creation.

In CCC it clearly says except massless all mass particle should vanish, for gravity is associated with mass particles.  This is accomplished by the so called black hole evaporation.  So let us assume the black hole evaporation leaves a clean space ready for next cycle which is achieved by collisions of multiverses.

In this cycle of birth and rebirth the left over radiation stands as a proof that it is taking place. To our amusement by the time the background radiation of the previous creation decays or vanishes another creation occurs.

This is only out of commonsense with no mathematical derivations.